# Measure number of rotations of DC motor using Hall encoder

Tags: dc-motor, hall-effect

I bought [this motor on aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32855724293.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.80.21ef1802g5VKSC) which comes with Hall encoder on (I bought the 12 V 1930 rpm version), and they said on the website:

> It is 11CPR for resolution for Hall encoder (this type is hall
> encoder);

and they also said:

> feedback signal  (11 pulse/rpm)

I don't understand how does this relate to that as they both have different meanings, anyways I bought the motors and tried it out but the problem is it produces non-uniform signal for the number of rotations depending on the speed of the rotation.
I used logic analyzer to notice the output signal of the encoder for only 1 revolution (made this revolution using my hand) and this is the graph:

[image]

and using saleae measuring tool, it told me that 186 pulses happened as stated in the next image:

[image]

I really can't determine the criteria through which I shall say that my motor has spent one revolution. Can anyone help me
as the results I get on my logic analyzer is different from that stated on the website?

Comment: If you run the motor at really low speeds, I can imagine that the sensor may give multiple detections. What's the lowest speed that you're hoping/needing to get the single revolution detect working at?

Comment: @TonyM, actually , after observing the output signals I noticed some glitches in encoder output signal same that  happens due to hardware debouncing in buttons, but the problem is that I can't find a criteria through I can make this work during the actual use of thus motor